# Indoor Navigation through Image Recognition Android Vuforia

Tags: android, vuforia, indoor-positioning-system

I want to implement indoor navigation through image recognition using Vuforia tool which works collaboratively with Android SDK.

I have collected the images that I want to use and now I have succesfully replaced the default picture of ImageTargets appication so as to add my own pictures.

My problem is the step further, since when this application recognizes a museum exhibit diplays a teapot.I want to replace this teapot with arrows that will help museum users to navigate into the museum.

How can I do it?There is an article to the official website of Vuforia which partially clarifies what must have happened but it's far from comprehensive(https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/replacing-teapot).

Any help might be totally crucial for me
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to create your arrow models in a program such as [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) or [Autodesk Maya](http://www.autodesk.com/products/autodesk-maya/overview) and export it as a *Wavefront OBJ* file. You may have to tweak some plugins/settings in your chosen modelling software to enable that option.

Then you need to convert that *.obj* file to a C/C++ include file (*.h*) to work with the native code in `ImageTargets.cpp`. There is a convenient Perl script that you can download to make this process easier - [OBJ2OPENGL](http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/).

Then it is a matter of importing your new model in `ImageTargets.cpp`, e.g. `#import "arrow.h"` then replace the code to draw the teapot with the following:

```
// set input data to arrays
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, arrowVerts);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, arrowNormals);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, arrowTexCoords);

// draw data
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, arrowNumVerts);
```

Don't forget to rebuild the project using *ndk-build* when you're finished.